# Advertencia al tratar de eliminar un fichero

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de borrar un fichero que está almacenado en mi servidor, pero ocurre la siguiente advertencia:

> Notice: Undefined variable: ruta_pdf in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\repositorioApp\appRegistroEventos\mainApp\deleteFile.php
>   on line 8
>
> Warning: unlink(../Uploads/Files/): Permission denied in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\repositorioApp\appRegistroEventos\mainApp\deleteFile.php
>   on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ruta_pdf in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\repositorioApp\appRegistroEventos\mainApp\deleteFile.php
>   on line 9 No se pudo borrar el fichero:

Estoy ejecutando la función de la siguiente manera:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
   ng-href="mainApp/deleteFile.php">
</a>
```

Como es un archivo único por usuario entonces requiero buscar el nombre del archivo para ubicarlo y poder borrarlo con la función `unlink()` pero retorna la advertencia y no me borra el archivo especificado.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id_empresa  = $_SESSION['usuario']['id_empresa'];
    require 'conexion.php';

    $selectFile = $mysqli->query("SELECT ruta_pdf FROM empresa WHERE id_empresa=".$id_empresa.";");

  if (!unlink("../Uploads/Files/".$ruta_pdf['ruta_pdf'])) {
    echo "No se pudo borrar el fichero: ".$ruta_pdf['ruta_pdf'];
  }
  else {
    echo "El fichero ".$ruta_pdf['ruta_pdf']." ha sido eliminado";
  }

  $updateFile = "UPDATE empresa
                                        SET ruta_pdf = ''
                                    WHERE `empresa`.`id_empresa` = '$id_empresa'";

  if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $updateFile))
    {
        echo "Datos actualizados correctamente";
    header("Location: ../");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error al actualizar: " . $mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Comprueba mi respuesta. En mi edición he agregado un control para detectar cuándo la consulta SQL ha ido mal (que es lo que te ocurre en la segunda consulta).

Comment: te recomiendo verificar si existe la ruta y tambien colocarla todo en minunscula o mayuscula si tu aplicacion se llega a instalar en un servidor linux te dara dolores de cabeza editar el codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás tratando de acceder a un registro que ha devuelto una consulta sin obtenerlos previamente con un [`mysqli::fetch()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.fetch):

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'conexion.php';

/* Esta es la consulta SQL */
$selectFile = $mysqli->prepare("
  SELECT ruta_pdf
  FROM empresa
  WHERE id_empresa = ?
");
/* Comprobamos si la consulta se preparó correctamente */
if ($selectFile === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . $mysqli->error);
}
/* Asignamos al primer "?" el valor de "id_empresa" */
$selectFile->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['usuario']['id_empresa']);
/* Comprobamos si la consulta se ejecutó correctamente */
if ($selectFile->execute() === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . $selectFile->error);
}
/* Cada vez que llamemos a "fetch" se asignará el resultado a $ruta_pdf */
$selectFile->bind_result($ruta_pdf);
/* Aquí obtenemos el registro (si lo hay) */
if ($selectFile->fetch() !== true) {
  die('No existe el registro a borrar');
}

if (!unlink("../Uploads/Files/".$ruta_pdf)) {
  echo "No se pudo borrar el fichero: ".$ruta_pdf;
} else {
  echo "El fichero ".$ruta_pdf." ha sido eliminado";
}
```

Comment: Suelo usar en una consulta este tipo de funcion:
$resultadoConsulta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM xxxx");

Comment: ¿Entonces qué puedo hacer para ayudarte? ¿Modificas la pregunta con el código exacto o te vale mi respuesta?

Comment: he modificado el codigo en la pregunta

Comment: He adaptado mi respuesta al cambio a mysqli

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\repositorioApp\appRegistroEventos\mainApp\deleteFile.php on line 16       obtuve este error como respuesta

Comment: Fue una pequeña confusión (estoy programando de cabeza, usé PDO/mysql por error). Prueba ahora con `bind_param`.

Comment: No es la primera vez que vos me ayudas, excelente!

Comment: Un placer servir de ayuda, me alegra que te funcione :)

Comment: tengo una pregunta, cuando llamas en el codigo die('Error SQL: ' . $selectFile->error()); **error()** como si fuese una funcion?

Comment: Disculpa, escribí el código de memoria :( no, no es un método, es una propiedad. Ya está editado.

Comment: no hay problema, suele suceder jajaja